# Change datasource for Dataset

Tags: vb.net

May I ask a question.

I have a vb.net window application project that connect to Access database.

I use dataset for all Forms and Reports.

Now I would like to change back end from Access database to SQL Server 2000 database.

I change the connection string(Data source, Data Provider etc)to connect to SQL Server 2000.

But it is not convenience bcos Dataset Designer codes are still connect with OLEDB Provider instead of Sql Client Provider.

So I can't do my application with SQL Server database.

May I request suggestion how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the go ahead to change the connection type?  If you have the code and your superior (or yourself if there is no superior) allows you to do so, it shouldn't be hard to change the connection type.  If there are any hardcoded queries though, you might have syntax issues you'll have to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have an equivalent to MS Access' Form and Report objects that you can import.  You can using the upsizing wizard to migrate the tables and queries, but you'll need to recreate the relationships on the SQL Side as the don't upsize.

Basically, swapping out an Access back end for a SQL Server one is conceptually easy, but from a development point of view, takes a fair amount of work.